# How to distinguish "..." to "." with Python

Tags: regex, string, python-2.7

I would like to reshape a sentence with specific indications. More precisely, I would like to do the following :

```
sentence = "This is... a test."
reshaped_sentence = "This is ... a test ."
```

To do this I use replace() function :

```
sentence.replace("...", " ... ").replace(".", " . ")
```

But I obtain the following :

```
reshaped_sentence = "This is . . . a test ."
```

I really need to distinguish ... from . in my sentence, so any idea how to correct this problem ?

Comment: Obviously the second replace will affect the first

Comment: Wictor's answer below will do what you need given 1 or 3 periods. Are you sure you don't also need to deal with [Unicode ellipses](http://www.charbase.com/2026-unicode-horizontal-ellipsis)?

Comment: @Jedi for the moment I'm not concerned with Unicode ellipses, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regular expression to match either 3 consecutive dots or a single dot enclosed with 0 or more whitespace chars, and replace that with the match value enclosed with spaces. To get rid of the trailing or initial whitespace, just call `strip()`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TZidh5):

```
import re
rx = r"\s*(\.{3}|\.)\s*"
s = "This is... a test."
print(re.sub(rx, r" \1 ", s).strip())
# => This is ... a test .
```

Here, `\s*(\.{3}|\.)\s*` matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\.{3}|\.)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `\.{3}` - 3 dots
  - `|` - or
  - `\.`  - a single dot
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xDXeIY/1).

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much, it seems to work :)
And now if I want to only process "..." and to remove ".", how can it been achieved ?
My sentence would be : s = "This is ... a test"

Comment: @Julian Since you are using Python 2.x, it will require a lambda expression in the replacement. [`re.sub(rx, lambda x: r" {} ".format(x.group(1)) if x.group(1) else " ", s).strip()`](https://ideone.com/tjedvJ)

Comment: This is just perfect :) Thanks a lot for the clarity of your explanations

Comment: @Julian: Just to clarify: in Python 3, you would also need a lambda. I did not account for the fact we need to replace `\s*\.\s*` with a space to actually make it work before I wrote the first sentence in the above comment.